# content under LazyVerticalGrid

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I don't understand why the content is not showing under LazyVerticalGrid

i want to add content under LazyVerticalGrid and see something like this

[image: good state]

but if i do height of card larger i dont see button

[image: bad state]

i dont understand why its not working

My Code:

```
val list = (1..10).map { it.toString() }

Column(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxSize()
) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(GridCells.Fixed(3),

        contentPadding = PaddingValues(
            start = 12.dp,
            top = 16.dp,
            end = 12.dp,
            bottom = 16.dp
        ),
        content = {
            items(list.size) { index ->
                Card(
                    backgroundColor = Color.Red,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(4.dp)
                        .height(100.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    elevation = 8.dp,
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = list[index],
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        fontSize = 30.sp,
                        color = Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                    )
                }
            }

        }
    )
    Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `weight(1f, fill = false)` on your `LazyVerticalGrid`,

```
    val list = (1..10).map { it.toString() }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        LazyVerticalGrid(
            GridCells.Fixed(3),
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f, fill = false),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(
                start = 12.dp,
                top = 16.dp,
                end = 12.dp,
                bottom = 16.dp
            ),
            content = {
                items(list.size) { index ->
                    Card(
                        backgroundColor = Color.Red,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(4.dp)
                            .height(180.dp)
                            .fillMaxWidth(),
                        elevation = 8.dp,
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = list[index],
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                            fontSize = 30.sp,
                            color = Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                        )
                    }
                }

            }
        )
        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {

        }
    }
```